# Памперс и ксерокс

Tags: грамотная-речь

На одном сообществе человека, написавшего "пачка памперсов" поправили: надо писать "пачка подгузников". Понятно, что "Pampers" — это фирма, равно как и "Xerox". Но эти слова настолько прочно вошли в речь, что мы даже не задумываемся над тем, что это название фирм. А являются ли эти слова сейчас литературными или так и остались просторечными?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В "Большом толковом словаре" под ред. Кузнецова никаких помет к этим словам не стоит, слова активно применяются на разных стилях общения, от разговорного до официально-делового и научного, следовательно их вполне можно считать литературными словами.

Answer (score 0):

Словари пишут кто угодно и как угодно, не вдаваясь в суть и смысл слова. [Xerox](http://ru.forvo.com/search/Xerox/en/) произносится [зирокс]. В школьных учебниках забыли написать что "X" в начали слова читается как "З". И вот толпы неграмотных людей с высшим образованием столкнулись с копировальным аппаратом Xerox и стали называть копирование ксероксом. А там уже в массы перекинулось это слово. А потом какой-то грамотей, привыкший с детства к слову ксерокс, решил: сделаю-ка я онлайн словарь. И добавил в него несуществующее слово.